# Handlebars: Display HTML markup based on 'nth'

Tags: handlebars.js, bootstrap-4, helper

I'm fairly new to Handlebars so you'll have to excuse my naiveté.

I'm currently working on a Handlebars blog template that utilizes Bootstrap 4 as a CSS framework. For my articles, I would like to iterate through a pattern that repeats itself after the 5th article is displayed on the homepage.

My first article's markup would be the default. Every 2nd and 3rd would use a different block of markup and same with every 4th and 5th.

If you review my code below you will see I am using placeholders for conditionals at the moment (e.g; 'every-2nd & every-3rd'). I am just not sure what I should do here and I haven't been able to find a helper to solve my problem.

```
<div id="main" class="col-md-8">

  {{#each content}}

    {{#if every-2nd & every-3rd}}

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>{{title}}</h4>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <button>{{button_text}}</button>
      </div><!-- /.col -->

    {{else if every-4th & every-5th}}

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img src="{{img_src}}" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h4>{{title}}</h4>
        <button>{{button_text}}</button>
      </div><!-- /.col -->

    {{else}}

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="{{img_src}}" />
        <h4>{{title}}</h4>
        <button>{{button_text}}</button>
      </div><!-- /.col -->

    {{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I'll advise you to use a "test" helper that will check for your index loop number.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('test', function(lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {
    var doDisplay = false;
    var items = (""+rvalue).split("|");
    var arrayLength = items.length;
    for (var i = 0; (i < arrayLength); i++) {
        if (operator == "eq") {
            if (lvalue == items[i]) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        } else if (operator == "ne") {
            if (lvalue != items[i]) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        } else if (operator == "gt") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) > parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        } else if (operator == "lt") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) < parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        }else if (operator == "le") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) <= parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        }else if (operator == "ge") {
            if (parseFloat(lvalue) >= parseFloat(items[i])) {
                doDisplay = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (doDisplay) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
});
```

So your code will look like that after using the helper :

```
<div id="main" class="col-md-8">    
  {{#each content}}    
    {{#test @index 'eq' '1|2'}}    
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>{{title}}</h4>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <button>{{button_text}}</button>
      </div><!-- /.col -->
    {{/test}}
    {{#test @index 'eq' '3|4'}}
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img src="{{img_src}}" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h4>{{title}}</h4>
        <button>{{button_text}}</button>
      </div><!-- /.col -->
    {{/test}}
    {{#test @index 'ne' '1|2|3|4'}}    
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="{{img_src}}" />
        <h4>{{title}}</h4>
        <button>{{button_text}}</button>
      </div><!-- /.col -->
    {{/test}}    
{{/each}}
```

Let me know in comments if you need more explanations

Comment: Thanks, Christophe. I just realized that this project is actually using Hapi and not vanilla Handlebars script. So I will have to convert what you wrote into Hapi script. I'll let you know how it works when I've had a chance to do so. Cheers!